# how can i get value from c file in php

Tags: php

I have created a c file and now i want to call that file in my PHP  function. as like curl. how can i do that??

Is there any function available in php to get value from c file. how can i do that i am not getting the exact path.

I have tried the code

```
$my_file = 'C:\TurboC3\BIN\DOLL.CPP';
//file_put_contents($my_file, $data);

system("gcc {$my_file} &> error.txt");

$error = file_get_contents("error.txt");

var_dump($error);

if($error=='')
    system("./a.out");
else
    echo $error;
```

but this is not working can any one tell me any other command.

Comment: which of these lines is not working ?

Comment: Actually I want to get response from c file. and when I am printing $error it is showing nothing. and when i am running c file in c compiler it is showing proper response.

Comment: did you get a chance to see if error.txt is being created . And if yes, is the path correctly being referred to in file_get_contents() e.g if it is being created in c:\turboc3\bin directory , shou;ldn;t the call to file_get_contents be ("c:\turboc3\bin\error.txt");

Comment: yaa all path are correct. I have checked properly.

Comment: change this line system("./a.out"); to system("a.out"); and I guess it should work

Comment: The file is not created automatically in c directory. I have putted that in my project folder and running from there.

Comment: still this change should make your file visible to php, as ./a.out is something you will do when you are on unix/linux

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pass any arguments to the c script, then you add them after the path.
To get the data printed by the c script you set a variable:

```
exec("/path", $outputOfCFile);
```

Where $outputOfCFile will be an array of every line printed by the c script.

```
exec("/path/to/executable -i example");
```

If your c script accepts arguments then you add them to the string after the path to the executable file.

Comment: this is not working :( can you please elaborate more.

Comment: Not working I am not getting any response. can you send me any working example that can help me alot.

Comment: How are you using it exactly? Try to test it in an easy scenario. Make a "hello world" c script, then compile it to an executable file. Also, you may have to set the permission of the executable or owner of it to www-data for php to be allowed to execute it.

Comment: I am doing the same I have created c file with hello world program only. and then I am trying to access that via php and above is my php code currently i have tried -                                  $my_file = 'C:\TurboC++\Disk\TurboC3\BIN\DOLL.CPP';

 $error = exec($my_file); $error is showing no response.

Comment: Did you look at my edits? To assign the results of the exec to a variable, you have to set it as the second parameter of exec(). Also, I'm not sure on a windows server, I use Linux, but can the executable file be used by anyone? Also, this executable is on the same server as the php right?

Comment: Also, that's not how it works. You can't execute a CPP file, you have to compile it into an executable file.

Comment: yes. I am doing this on my local system this is windows.

Comment: You don't directly call the cpp file. You call the executable file compiled from the cpp file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62059/discussion-between-nidhi-sen-and-evade-captcha).